# How do I submit receipt for FSA reimbursement for my spouse's medical expense?

Tags: united-states, fsa, medical-bill

I and my two children are under Kaiser, while my husband is under a different medical plan (BlueShield of CA). I enrolled in medical FSA while he is not. I read online that his medical expense can be reimbursed through my FSA account, but on wageworks I do not see any option to select him as the person for which the expense was incurred. So how do I submit his medical bill for reimbursement? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use Wageworks for my HSA. I know there is a place to add a person to the list of Patient names. The "add new patient" button is right next the patient name pull-down. After you click it it has you add a first name, last name and relationship.

I have no idea if the the same option exists on the FSA accounts.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but couldn't add my husband's name to my wageworks account. Is there another more elaborate method to claim the reimbursement?